# Creating Multiline elements with list comprehension in a column gives error in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have created multiline elements with list comprehensions [to make it look like it's a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyOr0.png). Now, I want to put these elements into a column and create multiple columns side by side.

Code:

```
some_string = 'some string'
x_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
y_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

main_column = [
    [sg.T(some_string)],
    [[sg.Multiline(size=(10, 3), key=(x, y), disabled=True, justification='center', no_scrollbar=True)
      for x in range(len(x_labels))] for y in range(len(y_labels))]]

extra_column = [[sg.T(y_labels[y], justification='center')] for y in range(len(y_labels))]

layout = [[sg.Column(extra_column), sg.Column(main_column)]]

window = sg.Window('Table Test', layout, default_element_size=(12, 1), element_padding=(1, 1),
                   return_keyboard_events=True)
```

Which gives
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLAj2.png). As far as I understand, every layout or column object is a list of list of elements.

What I've tried:

- Checked if main_column can be used as the layout, which it does:

  ```
   some_string = 'some string'
   x_labels = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
   y_labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

   main_column = [
   [sg.T(some_string)],
   [[sg.Multiline(size=(10, 3), key=(x, y), disabled=True, justification='center', no_scrollbar=True)
     for x in range(len(x_labels))] for y in range(len(y_labels))]]

   layout = main_column

   window = sg.Window('Table Test', layout, default_element_size=(12, 1), element_padding=(1, 1),
                  return_keyboard_events=True)
  ```

This should mean it is a list of list of elements and can also be used inside a column element. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
main_column = [
    [sg.T(some_string)],
    [[sg.Multiline(size=(10, 3), key=(x, y), disabled=True, justification='center', no_scrollbar=True) for x in range(len(x_labels))] for y in range(len(y_labels))],
]
```

`main_colum[1]` is not a list of elements, but list of list of elements here. It mean `main_column` is not a list of list of elements.

`main_colum` should be revised to

```py
main_column = [
    [sg.T(some_string)]] + [
    [sg.Multiline(size=(10, 3), key=(x, y), disabled=True, justification='center', no_scrollbar=True)
        for x in range(len(x_labels))]
            for y in range(len(y_labels))
]
```